# Fonts are not rendered properly using Gradle mac app bundle

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, webview, griffon

The application exported using the createApp task of Gradle macAppBundle does not render the fonts properly.

The application is a `JavaFX` application developed using `Griffon`. The interface of the application is [JavaFX WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) which renders an html file. The html file imports css files pointing to several fonts. In other words, the WebView component imports several font files through a couple of css files. If I run the application using `Gradle` execute/run task, the application renders the fonts properly. However, the exported application using `Gradle macAppBundle createApp` does not render them. Thus, my best guess is that macAppBundle is the source of the problem.

I would appreciate if somebody can tell me how can I force Mac to allow the exported application accesses and renders the fonts.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds as if the `macAppBundle` plugin does not package all resources. Have you had a look at the JARs found in the app package? Search for the missing resource files

Comment: Thanks for the response. There is a Jar file that contains all the resources. In addition to fonts, there are html and javascript files which are loaded correctly. Even fonts are found. However, the exported application does not render them properly.